# How to bundle javascript library implemented in Typescript that works in browser with require, import and <script> tag?

Tags: javascript, typescript, bundle, webpack-2, umd

I'm developing a library writen in Typescript, now I want to publish this library.

The other users will include the library in the following way:

```
// Using require
const Library = require('library');
Library.someFunction();

// Using import
import Library from 'library';
Library.someFunction();

// Using script tag
<script src="dist/library.js"></script>
<script>
    Library.someFunction();
</script>
```

The main class of my library is a class that has only static functions:

```
export default class Library {

    public static someFunction(data: any) {
        // Do something...
    }
}
```

This is my webpack config:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: helpers.root('src/Library.ts'),
    devtool: 'source-map',
    output: {
        path: helpers.root('dist'),
        filename: 'library.js',
        library: 'Library',
        libraryTarget: 'umd',
        umdNamedDefine: true,
    },
    ...
}
```

This is generating a bundle this way:

```
(function webpackUniversalModuleDefinition(root, factory) {
    if(typeof exports === 'object' && typeof module === 'object')
        module.exports = factory();
    else if(typeof define === 'function' && define.amd)
        define("Library", [], factory);
    else if(typeof exports === 'object')
        exports["Library"] = factory();
    else
        root["Library"] = factory();
})(this, function() {
    ...
});
```

But the only way to import in my Angular 2 project is using the following code:

```
// Using require
const Library1 = require('library');
Library1.Library.someFunction();
// Using import
import * as Library2 from 'library';
Library2.Library.someFunction();
```

In the browser:

```
<script src="dist/library.js"></script>
<script>
    Library.Library.someFunction();
</script>
```

How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I could make it work by creating another file (entry.ts) that only export functions:

```
import {Library} from 'Library;

export function someFunction(): void {
    return Library.someFunction();
}
```

And changing the webpack config entry:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: helpers.root('src/entry.ts'),
    ....
}
```

Now I can import the library on the browser using script tags:

```
<script src="dist/library.js"></script>
<script>
    Library.someFunction();
</script>
```

And I can also import in my Angular 2 project:

```
import * as Library from 'library';
Library.someFunction();
```

This is the generated object:

```
{__esModule: true, someFunction: ƒ}
```

Previously was creating an object this way:

```
{__esModule: true, Library: ƒ}
```